# initialDate not working in bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, smalot-datetimepicker

My today Date is `16-1-2014` and I set default date is `17-01-2014` but this is not working

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   startDate: new Date(),
   autoclose: true,
   todayBtn: true,
   todayHighlight: false,
   initialDate: new Date(2014, 00, 17),

   //update: new Date(2014, 00, 17),
   // onRender: function(ev) {
   //   console.log(ev.date.valueOf());
   // },

   format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
   language: 'en'
})
```

[image: Source Code]

output show on calendar

I am using below library
[bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Don't know why that doesn't work and I can't find anything wrong with it.. so here's an alternative http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/CujDK/46/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/smalot/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js#L481) it looks like the `initialDate` is not considered at all if your input element has a value attribute.

So if you want `initiaDate` to be used, make sure your input doesn't have a value (i.e. `value=""` or no value at all).

Comment: @vijay what about accepting this? didn't it solve your issue?